# Google Plus 'Photo' App fade-up share feature -

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use the Share photo slide up feature that Googles 'photo' app adopts to share photo content

[image: Screenshot]

I am hoping for this to be a generic selector but can't find any reference to it so questions;

1->Is this a android centric selector that could work with all versions of android 4.x?

2->If answer to 1 is 'NO' then is there any samples of a fade-up layout (like in the picture) that you know of?

(PS - i'm NOT wanting to share to google plus, just simply want access to the share applications)

Comment: until `Android L` comes out this is going to have to be a custom view. It is however included in the Android L Preview called `Bottom Sheets` http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#

Comment: @tyczj do you know any examples of a 'custom view' that mimics the feature?

Comment: I do not know of any examples but I suppose you could do something with a FrameLayout which is hidden off the screen then translating it up when you need it